# transition ease-in but not work with ease-out

Tags: html, css

Transition ease-in on hover the text but not ease-out when mouseOver the text.

**Code is below:**

```css
.span-style{
           font-size: 1.2em;
            transition:all 1s ease-out;
}       
.span-style:hover{
    border-left:4px solid;
    border-right:4px solid;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class=" span-style">
     <span class="span-style__1"> Duration</span>
     <span class="span-style__2"> 40 Days</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a problem of the timing function in itself, but that you have not given the element a proper default for the properties you are transitioning to revert back to. Add zero-width borders in the default state:

```css
.span-style{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-left:0px solid;
    border-right:0px solid;
    transition:all 1s ease-out;
}       
.span-style:hover{
    border-left:4px solid;
    border-right:4px solid;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class=" span-style">
     <span class="span-style__1"> Duration</span>
     <span class="span-style__2"> 40 Days</span>
</div>
```